# Inserting multiple documents in mongo ignore if key exists continue_on_error=True not working

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

if my db is similar as given below:

> /* 1 */ {
>       "_id" : 1.0,
>       "imagename" : "pen1",
>       "qty" : 21.0 }
>
> /* 2 */ {
>       "_id" : 2.0,
>       "imagename" : "pen",
>       "qty" : 20.0 }
>
> /* 3 */ {
>       "_id" : 3.0,
>       "imagename" : "eraser",
>       "qty" : 25.0 }

and i have to insert following documents which contains a duplicate key which i have to skip usually it can be done through continue_on_error=True but its not working

```
db.products.insert(
    [{ _id:1,imagename: "pen1", qty: 21 },
     { _id:2,imagename: "pen", qty: 20 },
     { _id:3,imagename: "eraser", qty: 25 }]
)
```

using insert_many getting  `batch op errors occurred`

using insert_many(data,ordered=False) facing same issue `batch op errors occurred`

using insert getting `duplicate key error collection`

using insert(data,continue_on_error=True) getting same issue `duplicate key error collection`

```
using : pymongo Version: 3.9.0, 
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert()` is deprecated so shouldn't be used. As such `continue_on_error` is no longer a thing.

Use `insert_many()` with the `ordered=False` parameter, and wrap the command in a `try...except` to ignore any duplicate key errors. Any duplicate entries will be skipped and any new records will be inserted. Try this example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

try:
    db.products.insert_many(
        [{ '_id': 1 ,'imagename': 'pen1', 'qty': 21 },
         { '_id': 2 ,'imagename': 'pen', 'qty': 20 },
         { '_id': 3 ,'imagename': 'eraser', 'qty': 25 }], ordered=False)
except BulkWriteError as e:
    pass
```

Comment: This returns empty array on error.